# How to use Nuxt-child in nuxtjs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to use nuxt-child in my project. Because I don't wanna refresh page whenever a link was clicked on right area. Normally I used nuxt-child in many projects without any mistake, but in this project , I cant see my child page in parent page. I use extendRoutes to override my routes.

file directory

```
-| gallery/
---| detail/
------| child.vue
---| detail.vue
```

```
module.exports = {
  middleware: ['trailingSlash'],
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push(

      {
        name: 'gallery-subcategory',
        path: '/gallery/:subcategory',
        component: resolve('pages/gallery/subcategory.vue'),
      },
      {
        name: 'gallery-detail',
        path: '/photo-gallery/:subcategory/:header(.*)-:number([0-9]+)',
        component: resolve('pages/gallery/detail.vue'),
      },
```

i use pug. detail.vue

```
    .wrapper
      .left-area 
        nuxt-child
      .right-area
        .......
```

Comment: you can't have both tags of vuejs3 and vuej2, which ones are you using ?

Comment: i use composition api.